# WSO2 ESB JMS listener configuration at runtime

Tags: jms, listener, wso2, esb

I am trying to add new parameter from WSO2 admin console Transport Management -> JMS Listener screen (don't want to use axis2.xml as I want updates to be used by proxy services without re-starting servers - hope this is possible ?). While adding new parameter I am getting following error -

Error while initializing JMS listener
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement

Can you please advise what should be the format of parameter value. I am trying to add similar value as available under "default" or "myQueueConnectionFactory".

Comment: I also tested this using ESB 4.7.0 and I got the same error. I couldn't figure out how a new parameter is specified by looking at the docs http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Configuring+Transports

Comment: what is the new parameter you added? and what is the value you provided for it?

Comment: I tried to add new parameter called TestJMSProxyParam, with value as - <parameter name="TestJMSProxyParam" locked="false">
      <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter> 
      <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://myserver:61616</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
   </parameter>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your scenario and this seems to be a bug with ESB. Go to JMS Listener Configuration and click on `Update` without any change to the default parameter values. Even then the same error is thrown. So I have reported this issue at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2412.

Unfortunately for now you will have to configure the parameters through axis2.xml until this issue is fixed. You can enable/disable the listeners through management console without any issue.